# First order approximation of $\zeta$(s) at s=1

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, riemann-zeta

I was playing around with Wolfram Alpha.
I found one interesting thing when I asked it to evaluate this particular summation.$$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1+10^{-
10}}}$$
It returned this$$ \approx10^{10}+\gamma$$
That's right the number itself plus the Euler–Mascheroni constant.
I tried it for various other values and it turned out to follow the same pattern. As the value got smaller the closer it followed that pattern.
[Image of Wolfram Alpha result click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBbe.jpg)
So formally stating $$ \lim _{s \rightarrow0 } \zeta(1+s) = 1/s+ \gamma$$
Is this true?
And why is this true?
Could it be proven by taking the first order approximation of the zeta function.

Comment: Better now after your edit ! I shall fix my answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2633.pdf could be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}=\zeta (1+\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon }+\gamma -\gamma _1 \epsilon +\frac{\gamma _2 }{2}\epsilon
   ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ where appear  the generalized Stieltjes constants.

Comment: Refer to the comment by Claude for more details.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Please, don't call me *Sir*. I shall work on this tomorrow morning. Cheers & thank for the problem.

Comment: $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n n^{1-s} = (s-1) \int_1^\infty ( \sum_{n \le x} \frac1n) x^{-s}dx$ may help to show $\lim_{s \to 1} \zeta(s) - \frac1{s-1} $ $=\lim_{s \to 1} (s-1) \int_1^\infty ( \sum_{n \le x} \frac1n- \log(x)) x^{-s}dx=\lim_{s \to 1} (s-1) \int_1^\infty (\gamma+o(1)) x^{-s}dx = \lim_{s \to 1} \gamma+o(1) = \gamma$